# C# exclude complete form / usercontrol by using compiler constants

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'd like to exclude / include a complete form in my project. But when I add the needed `#if CONST` and `#endif` the compiler complains about resources that may get wrong names.

> warning MSB3042: A namespace or class definition was found within a conditional compilation directive in the file "Form1.cs". This may lead to an incorrect choice for the manifest resource name for resource "Form1.resx".

What does this mean?

And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Explanation: 
  A normal Form (created from a Template) consists of 2 .cs files and a .resx file.
  By eliminating the Form1 class you 'orphan' the resources.
- Workarounds:

  1. Make a simpler Form without resource file.
  2. use a #else tag to create empty stubs for the Form1 class
  3. Forget about the idea and only eliminate the (few) points where the rest of the program uses the Form.

I favor 3, what benefits do you expect from removing the Form?

Comment: There will be two versions of the program. Due to safety reasons some Forms (and functionality) should be excluded in the deployment version. So 3) is not a solution for me, because the Form still exists in the .exe.

Comment: Ps: workaround 2) solves all problems. There are no more warnings, even the designer works with the stubs (when reopened).

Answer (score 0):

If you did not set images and you don't use the resx for translations (i.e. your form is not localizable)  try to remove your Form1.resx.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `#if CONST` / `#endif` region, so that it is within the derived form class declaration encompassing the entire contents of the partial class in Form1.cs.  The default constructor will takeover, and your warning will go away.